# Is there a technical reason why the flash is disabled with film simulation bracketing on the X100t

Tags: flash, fujifilm, bracketing, fujifilm-x100

The Fuji X100t disables the flash when bracketing is enabled. This seems logical for things like ISO bracketing because several photo's are taken in quick succession.

However with film simulation bracketing, as far as I know, only a single image is captured and then converted using different simulation settings.

Is there a technical reason why the flash is disabled using using film simulation bracketing, or is this just an oversight in the firmware?

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question but you can shoot into RAF (RAW) in a standard way with a flash and create that "bracketing" later in the [Fuji RAW Converter 2.0](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/software/myfinepix_studio/rfc/) that allows you to apply all kinds of emulated films on your RAF.

Comment: Interesting. Does this produce identical results as the in-camera  simulation?

Comment: In my case (X-30) yes. Almost. There are all camera film emulations available. The target images may have very slightly different tonality or contrast thought. It's probably because of the different development algorithm SilkyPix RAW Converter uses.

Answer (score 1):

> "The Fuji X100t disables the flash when bracketing is enabled. This seems logical for things like ISO bracketing because several photo's are taken in quick succession. ... an oversight in the firmware?"

1: They don't want to put in a fast flash to keep up with the frame rate or risk shot-to-shot inconsistencies.

2: Probably, but there's a workaround.

Shoot RAW, and apply the film simulations after you’ve shot.

To do this, view a photo, then press Menu/OK. Go to Raw Conversion, Film Simulation, and choose the one you want to apply. Press Menu/OK, then press the Q button to tell the camera to create the new image. Press OK to save it.

If the RAW is already on your computer:

If you have existing .raf raw files, you can copy them back to a memory card (just put the files in DCM > 101_FUJI), and load that card in your camera, then perform the conversions as explained above.

Source: "[Use Fujifilm Film Simulations In Camera, and on Existing Raw Files](https://www.kirkville.com/use-fujifilm-film-simulations-in-camera-and-on-existing-raw-files/)" by Kirk McElhearn.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an oversight in the firmware, since *all* the bracketing and burst modes disable the Fuji flash hotshoe; probably to avoid recycling speed issues with rapid repeated shooting.